# Is it possible to print in the next line without retyping echo in Linux scripting?

Tags: linux, scripting

How to get an output like this in shell without retyping echo?

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
```

the code that i know is by retyping echo such as

```
echo "firstline"
echo "secondline"
echo "thirdline"
```

is it possible to print it the way that i want without retyping echo, and if, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put newlines in strings.

```
echo "firstline
secondline
thirdline"
```

or use the `\n` escape sequence with `$''`.

```
echo $'firstline\nsecondline\nthirdline'
```

or use `printf`

```
printf '%s\n' firstline secondline thirdline
```

`printf` automatically repeats until it uses up all the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is an -e option for echo:
-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

```
~$ echo -e "line1\nline2\nline3"
line1
line2
line3
```